# boto3 S3: update `expiry-date` on object

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

My object has attribute `'Expiration': 'expiry-date="Sun, 16 Jul 2017 00:00:00 GMT"'` that define when this object will be deleted - this date set by S3 from lifecycle rule. Is any way to update this date from boto3 to autodelete this object later? By the way I found the same datetime in attribute `x-amz-expiration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your object is probably already gone, there is already an answered question for that specific topic: [s3 per object expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185879/s3-per-object-expiry)

tl;dr: Expiration is per S3 bucket, but by emulating `touch` you can extend the expiry date of individual objects.

As you asked for a `boto3`-solution for that and such a solution isn't noted in the linked question, here is one with boto3:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

# Upload the object initially.
client.put_object(Body='file content',
                  Bucket='your-bucket',
                  Key='testfile')

# Replace the object with itself. That will "reset" the expiry timer.
# As S3 only allows that in combination of changing metadata, storage
# class, website redirect location or encryption attributes, simply
# add some metadata.
client.copy_object(CopySource='your-bucket/testfile',
                   Bucket='your-bucket',
                   Key='testfile',
                   Metadata={'foo': 'bar'},
                   MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```