# Uploading large files to s3 using signed urls then save url to database, and then delete unused objects in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

I'm looking for steps to solve the issue of deleting mistakenly uploaded files into S3 Bucket.

Steps to Reproduce Issue :

1. Front End / Client get signed url from the Server.
2. Front End / Client uploads **File1** onto the S3 Bucket.
3. Front End / Client get another signed url from the Server.
4. Front End / Client uploads **File2** onto the S3 Bucket.
5. Front End / Client calls the api to save the url of **File2** onto the database.

Here, **File1** is left orphan on the S3 bucket with no links in my database. In our case we are dealing with large video files, so bit concerned on the usage of the bucket.

**How do I delete these orphaned files from S3 bucket?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you considered? How do you even tell an orphaned file from a non-orphaned one?

Comment: I meant, orphaned file is one which dosent have its data saved to my db.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, any thing you can point me to ?

Comment: Just start with something. Write code that finds files and then determines whether the file is orphaned or not.

Comment: I did find a workaround with the lifecycle configuration (with tag based filter). Is that a good approach? @UlrichEckhardt

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Comment: It seems that S3 doesn't support expiration per object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185879/s3-per-object-expiry, and it only supports expiration on bucket. I think the presigned saved objects should be put in a `temp` bucket that has  one month expiration. And at step 5, you can move the legitimate objects to another "permanant" bucket.